# $$ in my rails console returns a value. What does it mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Simply giving $$ in my rails console returns a value. Code block is given for reference below:

```
2.0.0-p481 :010 >   $$
 => 4715 
2.0.0-p481 :011 >
```

What does the returned value mean?

Comment: Just google "ruby predefined variables" and go to [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) to see that it is the process id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns the current Process Id.

If you need a more readable version, you can `require 'English'` and then use the [aliases](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) `$PID` or `$PROCESS_ID`